# Change AD user expired password in Java

Tags: java, ldap, jndi

I'm using JNDI to change LDAP user's password. In most cases (when user's password isn't expired) this code works just fine:

```
public InitialLdapContext connect(String url, String securityPrincipal, String password) throws AuthenticationException, NamingException {
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", truststore);
        Properties env = new Properties();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, url);
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "EE\\" + securityPrincipal);
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PROTOCOL, "ssl");
        env.put("java.naming.ldap.version", "3");
        env.put(Context.REFERRAL, "follow");
        return new InitialLdapContext(env,null);
    }
```

But when user with expired password tries to change it my app throws:

```
Exception: javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 773, v1db1 ]
          com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(LdapCtx.java:3041)
          com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2987)
          com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2789)
          com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.connect(LdapCtx.java:2703)
          com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.<init>(LdapCtx.java:293)
          com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURL(LdapCtxFactory.java:175)
          com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURLs(LdapCtxFactory.java:193)
          com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getLdapCtxInstance(LdapCtxFactory.java:136)
          com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getInitialContext(LdapCtxFactory.java:66)
```

So my question is: Is it possible to change LDAP expired passwords? If it's possible, then tell how.

Thanx for help!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The problem was resolved by creating Super User in Ad, which has rights to change every AD password. And when AD user password is expired, then the Super User changes his password.

Comment: Not secure. No-one but the user himself should know his password. Otherwise all sorts of issues arise such as loss of non-repudiability, which has major legal consequences.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the password policy overlay you have to use the change-password extended request. It's not supported in the JDK but I've posted code for it in the [Oracle Java JNDI forum](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1155421&tstart=0).