# Java spring LDAP - Waring LDAP password expire

Tags: java, spring, active-directory

We are using active directory to manage user account. Now we want to use password policy to set max password age to force user reset password after 2 months. And we need to warn user after they login if his password is going to be expired soon (3 days, for example).
How can we obtain this? We are using Spring LDAP 1.3.0.
I googled and see the password max age property is set in domain. However, I don't know how to get this value.

Thanks
COL

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the extended password request and response controls to get this information. See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13342808/change-ad-user-expired-password-in-java/13355196#13355196) for a link to the necessary Java code.

Answer (score -3):

Credentials expiration date and time

Getting the date and time at which the password was last changed:

```
private final static long DIFF_NET_JAVA_FOR_DATE_AND_TIMES = 11644473600000L;
long adDateTime = Long.parseLong(pwdLastSet);
long milliseconds = (adDateTime / 10000) - DIFF_NET_JAVA_FOR_DATE_AND_TIMES;
Date pwdLastSetDate = new Date(milliseconds);
```

Getting the number of max days that could have the password:

```
private final static int ONE_HUNDRED_NANOSECOND = 10000000;
private final static long SECONDS_IN_DAY = 86400;
long maxPwdAge = Math.abs(Long.parseLong(maxPwdAgeStr));
long maxPwdAgeSecs = maxPwdAge / ONE_HUNDRED_NANOSECOND;
int maxPwdAgeDays = (int) (maxPwdAgeSecs / SECONDS_IN_DAY);
```

Getting the the date and time at which the password will expire

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(pwdLastSetDate);
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, maxPwdAgeDays);
Date credentialsExpiresDate = cal.getTime();
```

Comment: Complete rubbish. None of this goes anywhere near LDAP or the password policy. Do read the question.